# What is Empty Audio_TS folder on DVD for?

Tags: dvd

Why is Audio_TS empty?

What is the purpose of keeping it empty?

Can I do without this empty Audio_TS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [AfterDawn](http://www.afterdawn.com/glossary/term.cfm/audio_ts) it is for [DVD Audio](http://www.afterdawn.com/glossary/term.cfm/dvd-audio)
It is not used for DVD Video, but some players need it to be there to recognise the disc correctly

Comment: DVD Audio (or DVD-A) was one possible thing that was supposed to be the "next generation CD", like SACD.